# codeigniter mongodb update bulk data

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, codeigniter, mongodb-query

I want to update my database with bulk data, so that I am using the following code, but when i execute the following code all the fields in my database got changed.

```
 public function submit_employee_edit_details($data,$id)
    {
        $m = new MongoClient();
        $db = $m->selectDB('fleet');
        $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'employee');
        $collection->update(array('_id' =>  new MongoId($id)),array('set' => 
        array( $data)));

       return true;
     }
```

but when i use

```
$collection->update ( array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), array('$set' => array( 'name' => 'john' )) );
```

it works fine. So what to do to update bulk data?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that $data is a key->value map with the new values you want to update, you should use

```
$collection->update(array('_id' =>  new MongoId($id)),array('$set' => $data));
```

Comment: yes $data is key-value map_id
:
ObjectId("5a829dca8b9ed23c03000029")
name
:
"akku"
cell
:
"0582156831"
email
:
"asde@gmail.com"
type
:
"Clerk" this is my data, but when i use the above mentioned command it updates like the following_id
:
ObjectId("5a829dca8b9ed23c03000029")
set
:
Array and there is updated data inside array, but it makes error in my view page as the field names are inside array

Comment: sorry, is "$set", not "set", I fixed the typo in the answer.

Comment: Message: localhost:27017: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead. For example: {$mod: {<field>: ...}} not {$set: [ { name: "akku", cell: "0582156831", email: "asde@gmail.com", type: "Driver", emiratesid: "2018-02-01", passport: "2018-02-02", visa: "2018-02-03", cna: "2018-02-04", license: "2018-02-05", daman: "2018-02-06", defensive: "2018-02-07", gatepass: "2018-02-08", address: "qwsereeee", doc: "visa.doc" } ]}
it gives me the above error